# Error:(38, 63) error: anonymous is not abstract and does not override abstract method done(Object,Throwable) in ParseCallback2

Tags: android, image, parse-platform, imageview

I am trying to retrieve an image file (JPG), from parse.com and place it into an ImageView.  The code below gives me the following error:

```
Error:(38, 63) error: anonymous is not abstract and does not override abstract method done(Object,Throwable) in ParseCallback2
```

What is the problem here?

```
final ImageView mImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Appetizers");
query.addAscendingOrder("appetizer");
query.getInBackground("imageFiles", new GetCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
        if (object == null) {
            Log.d("test", "The object was not found...");
        } else {
            Log.d("test", "Retrieved the object.");
            ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile)object.get("imageFiles");
            fileObject.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        Log.d("test", "We've got data in data.");
                        // use data for something
                        mImage.?????

                    } else {
                        Log.d("test", "There was a problem downloading the data.");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: add `@Override` before the line where `done` method is defined

Comment: my bad, i did and thats what is giving the error, sorry, will edit

Comment: I checked the other issues and nothing seems to work

Comment: I checked that one and i have the right Parse Exception.  nothing worked there.

Comment: Maybe this is the wrong code to use.  All i am trying to do is grab an image from parse.com and place it in the image view.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your `ParseQuery` like this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<>("Appetizers");
query.addAscendingOrder("appetizer");
query.getInBackground("imageFiles", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseObject object, com.parse.ParseException e) {
       // Your code
    }
};
```

Comment: Ok, i did that and it highlights ... new ParseQuery("Appetizers") and from new GetCallback() - end of code with a warning "unchecked assignment: 'com.parse.ParseQuery' to com.parse.ParseQuery<com.parse.ParseObject>'" and i still get the error from above.